# css inherit child propeties

Tags: html, css

I want to give border-bottom to header.the border color should be same as its child font color.please find the html code and suggest me to proceed further.

```
<header>
  <div class="cblt-panel">
     <header>
          <a href="HomePage;jsessionid=9Z1DRLtK8FfgmVDhysv4fk8LKjj1rTpSpJcS99dvcbffT4KTZ9tN!91184445">
             <div class="header-wrapper header"> 
                <h1 class="dealer-name">Airport Chevrolet Cadillac</h1>
             </div>
          </a>

     </header>

   </div>
</header>
```

in the above markup, i want to set the border-bottom-color for outer header tag  same as the font color of child  h1 tag. is it possible ?

Comment: I tried border-bottom-color: inherit currentColor ;but i don't think it is correct process . iam very new to css so i don't have any pointer to proceed

Comment: CSS inheritance is per property only. color to color, border-color to border-color, etc...

Comment: thank you  BG_Insight. can we inherit the property from child also ?i mean same property?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve it through pure CSS. If you are able to use jQuery, it's quite simple:

```
var h1Color = $('.dealer-name').css('color');
$('header:eq(0)').css('border-bottom-color', h1Color);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S9svs/

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible: in CSS, parents never inherit from their children.

You can just make an element’s border color the same as *its own* content color (text color), namely by not setting the border color at all. But to use a color set on a child, you need JavaScript.

A better strategy is to combine the settings so that you simply set the color of a heading element and the color of an enclosing element to the same value. These settings need to be done in separate rules, though, e.g. `header { border-color: #060; } h1 { color: #060; }`.

Comment: In life, parents never inherit from their children

Answer (score 0):

If you surely want to do it dynamically then you have to use a **css preprocessor language** for it...

Like [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/)

Here you make dynamically define the css and use it like you do in javascript...

For example,

```
@color:#000;
header { border-bottom-color:@color; }
header h1 { color:@color; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is that `border-color`, if not set, uses the `color` property to define it's color, so in some occasions you may be able to do the opposite. eg:

```
header {
    color:red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

header a,header h1 {
    color:inherit;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/brTTT/

In the demo, hover to see the color change by just changeing the `header` `color` property.